# How to sort struct using qsort

Tags: c, pointers, qsort

I am trying to use qsort to sort a struct containing pointers.  Is the problem with the comparison function?  How do I fix so I can sort based on the cc.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef enum {
    PETROL,
    DIESEL,
    ELECTRIC,
    LPG,
    BIOFUEL,
    OTHER
} fuel_t;

typedef struct car_tag {
    unsigned cc;
    fuel_t fueltype;
} car_t;


typedef struct fleet_tag {
    car_t ** cars;
    size_t n_cars;
} fleet_t;

int car_comp(const void * vp1, const void * vp2) {
    const car_t* const c1 = vp1;
    const car_t* const c2 = vp2;
    if (c1->cc > c2->cc)
        return -1;
    else if (c1->cc < c2->cc)
        return 1;
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}


int main() {
    car_t array[] = {
        { 600, PETROL},
        {1200, PETROL},
        {1000, PETROL},
        {1600, DIESEL},
        {1000, ELECTRIC}
    };

    int size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);

    fleet_t fl;
    fl.n_cars = size;
    fl.cars = malloc(size * sizeof(car_t));

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        car_t* pc = malloc(sizeof(car_t));
        memcpy(pc, &array[i], sizeof(car_t));
        fl.cars[i] = pc;
    }

    // how to sort cars by cc
    qsort(&fl, fl.n_cars, sizeof(car_t), car_comp);

    // sort function doesn't correctly sort fleet of cars by cc
}
```

Comment: Fix what exactly?

Comment: @MadPhysicist "How do I fix so I can sort based on the cc"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the need for the dynamic allocation and memcpy invoke for each to-be-sorted car in this code *at all*.

You're building a pointer bed (a sequence of pointers) so why not just allocate that (which you're doing), and then store the addresses of each element from `array` there. Then, tailor your comparator to address what you're sending: an address of a pointer (pointer to pointer) and setup the dereferences accordingly

Add to that, you should be passing `fl.cars` to qsort, not `&fl`, and the sizeof argument therein is also wrong.

Finally, I don't know if you intentionally wanted to use a greater-than logic stack in your comparator, but that is exactly what you ended up with.

**Example**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef enum {
    PETROL,
    DIESEL,
    ELECTRIC,
    LPG,
    BIOFUEL,
    OTHER
} fuel_t;

typedef struct car_tag {
    unsigned cc;
    fuel_t fueltype;
} car_t;


typedef struct fleet_tag {
    car_t ** cars;
    size_t n_cars;
} fleet_t;

int car_comp(const void * vp1, const void * vp2)
{
    const car_t * const *pc1 = vp1;
    const car_t * const *pc2 = vp2;

    if ((*pc1)->cc > (*pc2)->cc)
        return -1;

    if ((*pc1)->cc < (*pc2)->cc)
        return 1;

    return 0;
}


int main() {
    car_t array[] = {
        { 600, PETROL},
        {1200, PETROL},
        {1000, PETROL},
        {1600, DIESEL},
        {1000, ELECTRIC}
    };

    int size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);

    fleet_t fl;
    fl.n_cars = size;
    fl.cars = malloc(size * sizeof *fl.cars);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        fl.cars[i] = array+i;

    // how to sort cars by cc
    qsort(fl.cars, fl.n_cars, sizeof *fl.cars, car_comp);

    for (int i=0; i<size; ++i)
        printf("%d (%u, %d)\n", i+1, fl.cars[i]->cc, fl.cars[i]->fueltype);

    free(fl.cars);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Output**

```
1 (1600, 1)
2 (1200, 0)
3 (1000, 0)
4 (1000, 2)
5 (600, 0)
```

`qsort` works by feeding it a sequence of "things", a length stating how many "things" there are, a size noting how big each "thing" *in the sequence* is, and finally a comparator function which will be fed the *address* of each "thing" during execution of the algorithm.

In your case, your "things" are pointers to `car_t` structures. In fact,

- Your sequence is a dynamic array of pointers; your "thing" is a pointer to a `car_t`.
- You length is `size`.
- Your size of each "thing" is the size of a pointer.
- Your comparator will access the *address* of two of your things (therefore, two *pointers*, so pointers to pointers), and act accordingly.

Therefore, the call becomes:

```
qsort(fl.cars, fl.n_cars, sizeof *fl.cars, car_comp);
```

Finally, note that the original `array` remains unchanged. The sort modified your pointer bed only. That was probably desirable, and I hope you understand how it works.